# How to construct a PouchDB select call to return all items where a field exists and is not an empty string

Tags: pouchdb

Here is a PouchDB select call which correctly returns all documents from a PouchDB database which have a field called 'templateDetails' with a subfield called 'areaName' where the value of 'areaName' is an empty string

```
selector: { 'templateDetails.areaName': ''}
```

How can a change this selector so that it returns all documents where 'templateDetails.areaName' *exists* AND is *NOT* an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the **$gt** operator (see [Query language](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html#query-language)).

For example,

```json
selector: { "templateDetails.areaName": { $gt: "" } }
```

This works because of the Collation Specification, best documented [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#collation-specification).

Below is a snippet demonstrating such a selector in action.  Document's with even numbered _id's have an empty string subfield value *or* a subfield that is a non-empty string, a non-string subfield, or no subfield at all.

```js
const gel = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
const cel = (name) => document.createElement(name);

// generate canned test documents 
function getDocsToInstall() {
  let docs = [];
  let i = 0;
  docs.push({
    _id: i.toString(),
    field: null
  });
  for (; i < 10; i++) {
    docs.push({
      _id: i.toString(),
      field: {
        subfield: i % 2 === 0 ? "" : i.toString()
      }
    });
  }
  docs.push({
    _id: (++i).toString(),
    field: {
      subfield: 9
    }
  });
  docs.push({
    _id: (++i).toString(),
    field: {
      subfield: null
    }
  });
  return docs;
}

let db;

// init db instance
async function initDb() {
  try {
    db = new PouchDB('test', {
      adapter: 'memory'
    });
    await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.reason);
  }
}

function showDocs(tbodyId, docs) {
  const tbody = gel(tbodyId);
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    let el = cel("tr");
    el.innerHTML = `<td>${doc._id}</td><td>${JSON.stringify(doc.field)}<td>`;
    tbody.appendChild(el);
  });
}

initDb().then(async() => {
  // get all documents
  const alldocs = (await db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true
  })).rows.map(row => row.doc);
  // display all document _id and field.subfield
  showDocs('alldocs', alldocs);
  // find documents where field.subfield have a non-empty text value.
  const result = await db.find({
    selector: {
      "field.subfield": {
        $gt: ""
      }
    }
  });
  // display all document _id and field.subfield
  showDocs('results', result.docs);

});
```

```css
th,
td {
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 4em;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.find.js"></script>
<pre>
<b>All Docs</b>
<table>
<tr><th>_id</th><th>field</th></tr>
<tbody id="alldocs"></tbody>
</table>
</pre>
<hr/>
<pre>
<b>Query: get all non-empty string subfields</b>
{
    selector: {
      "field.subfield": {
        $gt: ""
      }
    }
<table>
<tr><th>_id</th><th>field</th></tr>
<tbody id="results"></tbody>
</table>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. $gt: "" did not work out for me, I still got returned documents where templateDetails.areaName was '' and indeed documents where templateDetails.areaName was not present.

Comment: I was trying a different approach: I want to return only documents where template.areaName exists and is not equal to ''. To get only documents where template.areaName exists I did this: selector: { 
                  'templateDetails.areaName ': {"$exists": true}}, and that works. But if I try: selector: { 
                  'templateDetails.areaName': {"$exists": true},
                  'templateDetails.areaName': {"$gt": "" }},  then I get the error "An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name"

Comment: So I can't use templateDetails.areaName twice like that. I should add that I am working with PouchDB and PouchDB-find in an Electron app.

Comment: @user3738290 I have updated the snippet which demonstrates the solution.  There is no reason to use `"templateDetails.areaName": {"$exists": true}}`.  The snippet first display a summary of all documents `field` value, and then the results of the query.